# Какое время обработки PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Делал скрипт на обычном new mysqli();
Скрипт грузился 1 секунду на денвере.
Как только перешёл на new PDO(); скрипт начал обрабатываться 2 секунды.

В чём может быть причина?

Comment: В обоих случаях одинаково долго выполняется ;)

Comment: В солнечных бурях?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала хочется заметить, что new `mysqli()` ничем не "обычнее", чем `new PDO()`.

По самому же вопросу ответить особо нечего - "время обработки PDO" не имеет никакого значения, поскольку всеми обработками занимается база данных, и все время уходит только на неё. Хотя, конечно, нельзя исключать ситуацию, когда кривой код может ухудшить время работы скрипта. Но такое бывает очень редко.

В целом же, повторюсь, время обработки PDO не играет никакой роли и ничем не отличается от времени обработки mysqli.

Если соединение с БД занимает относительно долгое время, можно заменить хост с `localhost` на `127.0.0.1`.